# Jest: module not found

Tags: node.js, jestjs, node-modules

I'm using a **WASM** module which is referenced in `package.json` **as a tgz file**:

```
"ic-vetkd-utils": "file:ic-vetkd-utils-0.1.0.tgz",
```

After `npm install` the module is available in `node_modules` as normal:
[image: node_modules]

I can use this module successfully in our reactJS frontend, but importing it in a **Jest** test file leads to `Cannot find module 'ic-vetkd-utils' from 'tests/iccrypt-tests-js/my.test.js'`.

Only the pure import statement `import * as vetkd from 'ic-vetkd-utils';` already fails, without accessing any function of this module.

Any other module can be used without any problem in Jest...

I'm assuming that a specifig Jest config entry is missing, any hint is most appreciated!